# Extract text from images in python

Tags: python, image

I am trying to extract text from images ; but while trying to extract the text from below image I am unable to extract the text that falls inside a triangle structure (not only specific to triangle structure)

[image: sigma.PNG]

```
import tesserocr
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open('sigma.PNG')
print(tesserocr.image_to_text(image))
```

I am getting below text post extraction ; see the text inside the triangle has been ignored

> 'Me i an\nete\nEire aise)\n\n+ Defect! Variation Reduction\n+ Process Optimisation\ne + Waste Reduction\n\nPI um ny\n\nPerce etre eee ei ead\n\n \n\n+ ProcessEfficiency\n\n  \n   \n\n+ Process Documentation and Rigour\neo + ProcessMetrics and Controls\n\n+ Management Operating System eee Su\n\nFigure 18\n'